# Add nuget packages folder at solution level

Tags: asp.net-core, package, nuget

I have created an ASP.Net Core project in Visual Studio 2019. Also, I have added few packages. But there is no packages folder created at project level. I want all packages to install in packages folder at project level. What I am doing wrong? Please advise.

Comment: ASP.NET Core projects use PackageReferences. These are not local copied to the packages directory inside the solution. That happens for projects that use packages.config files - which is not supported with .NET Core projects. The NuGet packages will be in the directory - %UserProfile%\.nuget\packages - by default. There are ways to override this behaviour via a [NuGet.Config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) or MSBuild properties. Why do you need the packages in a folder inside the solution?

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I use Nuget.config as there is no Nuget.config file in my project?

Comment: You can add a NuGet.config file so it exists next to your solution (so it will not affect other solutions) and then you could set the globalPackagesFolder to a relative path - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section